# How to compare strings in arrays vertically in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, multidimensional-array

I am trying to solve one problem statement where I need to compare string in arrays vertically & horizontally like crosswords.

Here I am able to compare the `horizontally` as:

```
var arr1 = ["clue","hand","inst","land","door","or","lan","lue"];
var arr2 = [['c','l','u','e'],['h','a','n','d'],['i','n','s','t'],['l','a','n','d'],['d','o','o','r']];

for(var i=0; i < arr2.length;i++){
    //compares whether any words from arr2 present in arr2 
    if(arr1[i].indexOf(arr2[i].join(''))> -1){
        console.log("isVetical",arr1[i]); 
//this prints all the matching element from arr1
    }
}
```

in the same way how can check `character by character vertically` like crosswords.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: just turn the columns into arrays, and use the same routine you use to find row matches.

Comment: @dandavis ok, but how do get the column from a matrix so that the first column value will be : child  likewise?

Comment: var word = arr2[i].join();

Comment: @Exos arr2[i].join() will give let say first value  arr2[0].join() == clue not child

Comment: `function pluck(a){return a[this]} col0=arr2.map(pluck, 0);col1=arr2.map(pluck, 1); ... `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**Array.reduce()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to create the vertical text, then see if the `arr1` element is found within it:

```
for(i = 0 ; i < arr1.length ; i++){
  for(j = 0 ; j < 10 ; j++) {
    vert= arr2.reduce(function(prev, curr) {return prev+curr[j];}, '')
    if(vert.indexOf(arr1[i]) > -1) {
      output.innerHTML+= "isVertical: "+arr1[i]+'\n'; 
    }
  }
}
```

**Snippet**

```js
var arr1 = ["clue","hand","inst","land","door","or","lan","lue","child","sno"],
    arr2 = [['c','l','u','e'],['h','a','n','d'],['i','n','s','t'],['l','a','n','d'],['d','o','o','r']],
    output= document.querySelector('#output'),
    vert, i, j;

for(i = 0 ; i < arr2.length ; i++){
  if(arr1[i].indexOf(arr2[i].join(''))> -1){
    output.innerHTML+= "isHorizontal: "+arr1[i]+'\n'; 
  }
}

for(i = 0 ; i < arr1.length ; i++){
  for(j = 0 ; j < 10 ; j++) {
    vert= arr2.reduce(function(prev, curr) {return prev+curr[j];}, '')
    if(vert.indexOf(arr1[i]) > -1) {
      output.innerHTML+= "isVertical: "+arr1[i]+'\n'; 
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<pre id="output"></pre>
```